# Apache CXF :- How do i extract the payload data using cxf interceptors

Tags: java, apache, web-services, cxf, interceptor

What steps should I follow to extract the payload using Apache CXF interceptors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your interceptor needs to extend from the `AbstractPhaseInterceptor` or a subclass

```
public class MyInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {
    public MyInterceptor () {
        super(Phase.RECEIVE);
    }

    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        //Get the message body into payload[] and set a new non-consumed  inputStream into Message
        InputStream in = message.getContent(InputStream.class);
        byte payload[] = IOUtils.readBytesFromStream(in);
        ByteArrayInputStream bin = new ByteArrayInputStream(payload);
        message.setContent(InputStream.class, bin);
    }

    public void handleFault(Message messageParam) {
        //Invoked when interceptor fails
    }
}
```

Add the interceptor programmatically

```
MyInterceptor myInterceptor = new MyInterceptor();

Server server = serverFactoryBean.create();
server.getEndpoint().getInInterceptor().add(myInterceptor);
```

Or using configuration

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd">

    <bean id="MyInterceptor" class="demo.interceptor.MyInterceptor"/>

    <!-- We are adding the interceptors to the bus as we will have only one endpoint/service/bus. -->

    <cxf:bus>
        <cxf:inInterceptors>
            <ref bean="MyInterceptor"/>
        </cxf:inInterceptors>
        <cxf:outInterceptors>
            <ref bean="MyInterceptor"/>
       </cxf:outInterceptors>
    </cxf:bus>
</beans>
```

Check documentation [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html)

Comment: @ pedrofb what code do i write in the handleMessage method in order to get the payload...I am a novice in cxf..

Comment: Take a look at source code of CXF `LoggingInInterceptor.handleMessage` and `LoggingOutInterceptor.handleMessage`. These classes allow to print the full message in logs. You can copy and paste from there http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.cxf/cxf-core/3.1.1/org/apache/cxf/interceptor/LoggingInInterceptor.java#LoggingInInterceptor.handleMessage%28org.apache.cxf.message.Message%29

Comment: @ pedrofb  I have already printed the full message in the logs using LoggingInInterceptor and LoggingOutInterceptor.... I want to extract that payload in the java class when the end user sends the data....sorry if I am missing something here..

Comment: The message body is available in this way `InputStream in = message.getContent(InputStream.class);` In the link I have provided, you can see examples to get other fields (headers, etc) if you need it. Do you want to get the payload in client side or in server side?

Comment: Ok, then the code is correct. I have added the necessary code to get the payload.

Comment: @ pedrofb You are Awesome!! Thanks :)

Comment: Ok, consider to mark the response as correct or upvote if you think it has been helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LoggingInInterceptor` to retrieve payload as String

```
public class CustomInInterceptor extends LoggingInInterceptor {

    /**
     * SLF4J Log Instance
     */
    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomInInterceptor.class);

    /**
     * formats logging message and also attaches input xml to thread context
     * 
     * @see org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor#formatLoggingMessage(org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingMessage)
     */
    @Override
    protected String formatLoggingMessage(final LoggingMessage loggingMessage) {
  //The below line reads payload and puts into threads context, which I use later to save in db 
    KpContextHolder.setInputXml(loggingMessage.getPayload().toString());
        return super.formatLoggingMessage(loggingMessage);
    }

}
```