# Getting the raw request and response SOAP XML in CXF

Tags: c#, cxf

How can I get access to the raw request and response XMLs? I wrote an interceptor but message.getContent(String.class) return empty. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have a look at the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38586259/apache-cxf-how-do-i-extract-the-payload-data-using-cxf-interceptors/38594742#38594742

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see raw data you might be better off using WireShark or something like that, it will show the XML exactly as it's sent across the wire.