# Is it possible to send "False" response from Interceptors in Apache CXF and Spring SOAP WS?

Tags: spring, soap, cxf, interceptor, spring-ws

Consumer for one of my SOAP web service is unable to read SOAP Faults(Schema Validations) and hence he wants us to send "Ok = false" response instead with failing schema validation message.

I am not sure if we in any way can customize interceptors to generate a false response instead of SOAP Faults.

I am using interceptors for generating faults as of today as shown below

```
@org.apache.cxf.interceptor.InInterceptors(interceptors = {"com.xxx.piano.services.interceptors.RequestParserInterceptor",
    "com.xxx.piano.services.interceptors.RequestInterceptor"})
@SchemaValidation(type = SchemaValidation.SchemaValidationType.IN)
@org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutFaultInterceptors(classes =  RequestParsingValidator.class)
```

As of today I am getting a fault like below

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap:Body>
  <soap:Fault>
     <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
     <faultstring>[City is empty !] </faultstring>
  </soap:Fault>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

While I want something like below:

```
    <ns3:XXXServiceTypeResponse>
        <OK>false</OK>
        <Error>
            <Message>Duplicate Product Individual Identifier.</Message>
            <TechnicalDescription>Postal Code Missing</TechnicalDescription>
            <ErrorCode>E0022</ErrorCode>
        </Error>
        <ns3:ResponseID>01202662-0010-0001-0001-4617844469</ns3:ResponseID>
    </ns3:XXXServiceTypeResponse>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

With an interceptor is possible to customize the response, but I do not recommend to return a message that is not present in the WSDL, which is the contract between client and server.

Instead it would raise that the answers had error codes instead of generating soap faults. In this way your client will also be able to generate automatically the code for his programming language.

Each message have the status (ok), the error details, and the usual response if the status is correct

```
<ns3:XXXServiceTypeResponse>
      <OK>false</OK>
      <Error>
          <Message>Duplicate Product Individual Identifier.</Message>
          <TechnicalDescription>Postal Code Missing</TechnicalDescription>
          <ErrorCode>E0022</ErrorCode>
      </Error>
      <ns3:ResponseID>01202662-0010-0001-0001-4617844469</ns3:ResponseID>
      <ns3:ResponseIfOk />
  </ns3:XXXServiceTypeResponse>
```

Comment: Not sure if I understood properly @pedrofb.

Did you mean that we should try converting faults into a response object.
But consumer here cannot parse fault responses in my case. :(

Comment: Sure my english it is not too good. I propose not to use faults and change the object model. Instead of raising a fault in your businness logic, catch the exception and return the error code as an attribute of the returned object. Include this attribute in every one of your response messages. This scheme is very common in soap to avoid using faults ( i prefer use faults if possible)

Comment: Thanks. 
but then i want to construct a standard response for failing validation messages.
I have read elsewhere that it is not possible to create ServiceResponse messages from CXF Interceptors.
Will be great if you can explain soome good way of doing that.

Comment: With an interceptor you have access to the interchanged message. See in my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38587928/6371459 an interceptor to extract the payload of the message and set the new content if you want. You will need an OUT interceptor extending `AbstractPhaseInterceptor` (generic) or `AbstractSoapInterceptor`, get the payload, analyze the data and compose the new SOAP message. Your client will need also to parse the message directly because since the message format is not present in WSDL, its programming language wont' generate the appropiate code, so it will raise an exception